# algorithm to efficiently traverse or generate all list indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

there is an issue that i am trying to solve which requires me to generate the indices for an n - dimensional list. Eg: [5, 4, 3] is a 3 dimensional list so valid indices are [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0] ... [2, 2, 1] ..... [4, 3, 2]. The best I could come up with a recursive algorithm but this isn't constant space

```
def f1(dims):
     def recur(res, lst, depth, dims):
          if depth == len(dims):
            res.append(lst[::])
            return
      curr = dims[depth]
      for i in range(curr):
        lst[depth] = i
        recur(res, lst, depth + 1, dims)

    res = []
    lst = [0] * len(dims)
    recur(res, lst, 0, dims)
    return res
```

the dimensions can be any number , ie: 4D, 5D, 15D etc. Each time it would be given in the form of a list . Eg: 5D would be [3,2,1,5,2] and I would need to generate all the valid indices for these while using constant space ( just while loops and indices processing ) . How would I go about generating these efficiently without the help of any in built python functions ( just while, for loops etc )

Comment: Use `itertools.product()`

Comment: @Barmar I missed it too first but OP wants "without the help of any in built python functions "

Comment: Hint: think about how an odometer updates.

Comment: Why do you have to do it without built-in functions? If this is an academic exercise, we're not going to solve it for you.

Comment: How can you possibly do it in constant space? The number of indices you need is dependent on the input size, not a constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution in constant space (a single loop variable `i`, and a vector `idx` of which modified copies are being yielded, and a single temporary length variable `n` to avoid calling `len()` on every iteration):

```py
def all_indices(dimensions):
    n = len(dimensions)
    idx = [0] * n
    while True:
        for i in range(n):
            yield tuple(idx)
            if idx[i] + 1 < dimensions[i]:
                idx[i] += 1
                break
            else:
                idx[i] = 0
        if not any(idx):
            break


print(list(all_indices([3, 2, 1])))
```

Result:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (2, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0)]
```

As pointed out in the comments, there's duplicates there, a bit sloppy, this is cleaner:

```py
def all_indices(dimensions):
    n = len(dimensions)
    idx = [0] * n
    yield tuple(idx)  # yield the initial 'all zeroes' state
    while True:
        for i in range(n):
            if idx[i] + 1 < dimensions[i]:
                idx[i] += 1
                yield tuple(idx)  # yield new states
                break
            else:
                idx[i] = 0  # no yield, repeated state
        if not any(idx):
            break


print(list(all_indices([3, 2, 1])))
```

Alternatively, you could yield before the break instead of at the start of the loop, but I feel having the 'all zeroes' at the start looks cleaner.

The `break` is there to force a depth first on running through the indices, which ensures the loop never reaches 'all zeroes' again before having passed all possibilities. Try removing the `break` and then passing in something like `[2, 1, 2]` and you'll find it is missing a result.

I think a `break` is actually the 'clean' way to do it, since it allows using a simple `for` instead of using a `while` with a more complicated condition and a separate increment statement. You could do that though:

```py
def all_indices3(dimensions):
    n = len(dimensions)
    idx = [1] + [0] * (n - 1)
    yield tuple([0] * n)
    while any(idx):
        yield tuple(idx)
        i = 0
        while i < n and idx[i] + 1 == dimensions[i]:
           idx[i] = 0
           i += 1 % n
        if i < n:
           idx[i] += 1
```

This has the same result, but only uses `while`, `if` and yields the results in the same order.

Comment: Thanks, i am not clear why you have that break command though. are you forcing an early break so that i doesnt get incremented? is there a way to do it cleanly without breaking

Comment: also is there a way to generate those indices without duplicates? i can obviously add it to a set and easily remove duplicates but it needs to be correct by construction

Comment: I updated the answer - feel free to ask if it's still not clear.